# Drawing 3 lines html5 (alpha, beta, gamma via deviceorientation)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I would like to draw 3 lines using deviceorientation (alpha,beta,gamma data) via html5.

```
<html>
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
<script>
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(e) {draw(e.gamma, e.beta, e.alpha);}, false);

function draw(g,b,a)
{
  var gamma = Math.round(g);
  var beta = Math.round(b);
  var alpha = Math.round(a);

  var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
  var cx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // how can i draw this 3 lines ?
}
</script>
</html>
```

Here is an example of the three vectors (lines) :

[image]

Demonstration : [ http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/Gyroscope_wheel_animation.gif ]

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information on how each of your three lines relate to alpha, beta and gamma.

Comment: i've added an example (alpha: z axis, beta : x axis and gamma : y axis)

Comment: What I do not understand is what lines on the screen are you wanting. Suppose the device was lying on the table what would the three lines look like on the screen? If the device is held vertically what would the three lines look like on the screen?

Comment: if the device was lying on a table so it depends on alpha maybe the device is oriented on your left or right (because gamma and beta will be equal to 0) if you have a device you can test with this link (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/deviceorientationsample.html)

Comment: You have still not stated anything about what are the three lines you wish to draw. Last question to try to understand. If alpha=beta=gamma=0 how would the three lines appear on screen. If alpha=gamma=0 and beta=90deg how would the three lines appear on screen.

Comment: Ok i hope i'll explain it well with this image : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Gyroscope_wheel_animation.gif
what i need is drawing this three lines wich they represent gamma,alpha and beta (z x y) hope you understand

Comment: You need a 2D representation of the 3D axes x,y,z which changes depending on the orientation of the device. First of all I suggest you look at http://threejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what your requirements are. Here are some suggestions:

1. Use three.js, and draw axis. Here is an [example](http://soledadpenades.com/articles/three-js-tutorials/drawing-the-coordinate-axes/).
2. Attach your three.js control with DeviceOrientation. Three.js already provide such control within THREE.DeviceOrientationControls. Here is an [example](https://github.com/richtr/threeVR).
3. Position your THREE.PerspectiveCamera in a point where you can see clear all the axes.

I know it is an old post, but hope it helps.